What is the physical meaning of Bogoliubov's fermions in the context of the 1D transverse field Ising model?
As I understand it, the 1D transverse field Ising model describes the physics of a chain of spin-1/2 particles. Now, to find the energy spectrum of this Hamiltonian at some point a Bogoliubov transformation is introduced to diagonalize the Hamiltonian, which results in the following form
$$ H = \sum_p \varepsilon(p) \left(\gamma_p^\dagger \gamma_p - \frac{\mathbb{I}}{2} \right).$$
Now, in the context of quenched dynamics (see section 1.3 in  [Calabrese2012]), it is mentioned that the time regimes of the dynamics of the correlation functions are "determined by the propagation velocity of the elementary excitations of the post-quench Hamiltonian" which is given by the differentiating $\varepsilon(p)$ with respect to $p$.
My problem is that I am unsure what these elementary excitations are. My first guess is that they are referring to the Bogoliubov fermions, however, even if that is the case, what do they physically represent? What is "propagating" in this spin chain?

the details of the calculations that describe the physical content of those operators is found in Appendix A in your reference. I will use it as a reference and elaborate on it a bit.
We have a system of spins and we want to map it onto some Fermionic creation and annihilation operators. We start by defining the vacuum as the all-up state $|\rm{vac}\rangle = \prod_j \otimes |\uparrow\rangle_j$, and then use a Jordan-Wigner transformation to define creation and annihilation operators at site $j$ by Eq. (A.3) in the appendix. You can check that they satisfy $\left\{c^{\dagger}_j, c_i\right\} = \delta_{i,j}$. Note that the transformation is non-local, as we attach a chain of $\sigma^z_i$ to each of these operators. So these (non-local) operators act more or less as lowering or raising the spin at site $j$ (this is the local part), with a phase depending on the state of the rest of the chain (this is the non-local part).
We can now Fourier transform those operators and create $c^{\dagger}_k$, which creates a "traveling wave" of spin raising with wave number $k$. So this state is a superposition of raised spins along the chain, such that a wave is created. This is similar to the waves constructed by $\psi^{\dagger}_k$ of creation and annihilation of electrons, only the nature of the local excitation is a spin raising rather than creation of an electron.
This transformation does not diagonalize the Hamiltonian yet (see Eq. (A.6), as you can check that even the vacuum is not an eigenstate. Also - the resulting Hamiltonian does not conserve the number of "particles" (or excitations) as it can create or annihilate pairs of them, but this is ok - they are not real particles (this is similar, by the way, to the superconducting Hamiltonian where pair of electrons can be created from the bulk).
To finish the diagonalizatoin process we choose a sector with either even or odd number of excitations (the parity is conserved) and then do the Bogoliubov transformation described in Eq. (A.11). Those excitations are superpositions of creation and annihilation operators, with amplitudes depending on $k$. So the physical context here is a superposition of traveling waves of raising and lowering of spins.
If you want, you can work backwards from one of the Bogoliubov quasi-particles, plugging first $c^{\dagger}_k$ and $c_k$ into $\alpha^{\dagger}_k$, and then plugging the spin operators into the $c_k$'s, to get how that looks in terms of spins.
